# PHP Mysql Replace value in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

How to replace value in database to another value during view?

Let say in database , 'type' data stored in database is 1 but during view i need to replace to string value "home loan"

[Sample data in database](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/5946/k543.png)

This is my coding in php:

```
$loans = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loans");

echo "<table cellspacing='2'>";

echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th width=70>Type</th><th width=70>Amount</th><th width=70>Duration</th><th>Installment</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loans)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row["loan_id"] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row["type"] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row["amount"] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>"  . $row["duration"] .  "</td>";

    echo "<td>"  . $row["installment"] .  "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  if($row["type"]==1){ 
     echo "<td> Home Loan </td>";
  } else { 
     echo "<td>other type</td>"; 
  }
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

A simple if condition will work for this.

```
if($row['type'] == 1) {
    echo "<td>home loan</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>" . $row["type"] . "</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create another table with values associated with each of the types and join the value on that table.

Table loan_types

```
id | loan_type
1  | Home Loan
2  | Other Loan
```

Then your query

```
<?php
$loans = mysql_query("SELECT loans.*, loan_types.`loan_type` FROM loans LEFT JOIN loan_types ON loans_types.`id` = loans.`type`");
?>

<table cellspacing='2'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th width=70>Type</th>
        <th width=70>Amount</th>
        <th width=70>Duration</th>
        <th>Installment</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loans)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["loan_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["loan_type"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["amount"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["duration"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["installment"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i like this approach:

```
$types = array(1=>"Home Loan");

$echo_type = isset($types[$row['type']])?$types[$row['type']]:$row['type'];
echo "<td>".$echo_type."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loans)) {

   printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",$row["loan_id"],$row["name"], ((int)$row["type"] === 1 ? 'home loan':'other'),$row["amount"], $row["duration"], $row["installment"]) ;
}
```